# Add irq handler for keyboard in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write simple kernel module that can give a random number for user by registering shared interrupt handler to keyboard or mouse interrupts and reading timestamp in virtualbox. The problem is that is can't find out how does virtualbox handle the keyboard or mouse interrupts and which irq number should I use?

cat /proc/interrupts output:

```
          CPU0       
  0:         30   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:         38   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
  8:          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:          0   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
 12:        158   IO-APIC  12-edge      i8042
 14:          0   IO-APIC  14-edge      ata_piix
 15:        769   IO-APIC  15-edge      ata_piix
 16:        329   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   enp0s8
 18:        713   IO-APIC  18-fasteoi   vmwgfx
 19:       5387   IO-APIC  19-fasteoi   enp0s3
 20:        327   IO-APIC  20-fasteoi   vboxguest
 21:      28865   IO-APIC  21-fasteoi   ahci[0000:00:0d.0], snd_intel8x0
 22:         26   IO-APIC  22-fasteoi   ohci_hcd:usb1
NMI:          0   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:      82937   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:          0   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:          0   Function call interrupts
TLB:          0   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
DFR:          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
MCE:          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:          3   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
PIN:          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
NPI:          0   Nested posted-interrupt event
PIW:          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event
```

Comment: IRQ 1 will be the PS/2 keyboard IRQ and IRQ 12 will be the PS/2 aux (mouse) IRQ. It is possible that your VirtualBox instance will also be emulating another pointing device connected to the virtual USB controller.

Comment: The user process could just use /dev/random or /dev/urandom to read random numbers. A portion of that randomness (entropy) already comes from timing input events from mice and keyboards etc.

Comment: The IRQ 1 and IRQ 12 PS/2 interrupts I mentioned earlier are handled by "drivers/input/serio/i8042.c" on current kernels.

Comment: Hmm, is it ok that amount of interrupt calls on IRQ 1 and IRQ 12 does not change after I type smtn or move the mouse?

Comment: I would expect keyboard interrupts on IRQ 1. If you have "Pointing Device" in the VM's system settings configured as "PS/2 Mouse" then I would expect interrupts on IRQ 12 when you move the mouse.

Comment: It started working with PS/2 Mouse option set, thanks!